# Where do I find a free (open source preferably) VNC management tool?

Tags: vnc, vncserver

I am trying to get remote internal setup for our business. Basically, I just want to remote desktop into any computer on the network. I don't want to use LogMein, because I only want it to be internal for security.

Basically, I am looking for a way to just install VNC clients on all the machines, and on my machine have centralized manager for all the machines that are connected to it.

Doesn't have to VNC - just needs to work and be free.

All systems running Win 7 64bit

Comment: What do you mean by "centralized manager"?  Do you just want a listing of all computers and be able to double-click one to connect?  or are you looking to see who is connected to what computer in real-time, disable remote connections, etc.?

Comment: Having the ability to see everything in real time sure would be nice, but it needs to have the ability to just see all the computers and connect to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Remote Desktop Manager](http://remotedesktopmanager.com/), I've found, is the simplest and most powerful remote connection manager.  It keeps a hierarchical list of all connections, and can keep track of a huge number of types of connections: RDP, VNC, PCAnywhere, TeamViewer, LogMeIn, DameWare, FTP, SSH, Telnet, VMWare, Hyper-V, X11, Citrix, VirtualBox, etc.

The programs can store its list of connections in an MDB which can be put on a file share so multiple computers can have the same database, or the Enterprise version supports storing on SQL Server or Amazon S3.

---

For the actual connection, I agree with Owen and say you should probably just use Remote Desktop.  I've found it's the fastest and best engineered of the remote desktop solutions.

If you're trying to help another user on their logon (as you mentioned in a comment), you should install [Remote Assistance](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Windows-Remote-Assistance-frequently-asked-questions) on each of the computers.  It's a feature built-in to Windows that allows screen sharing; I use it myself since I have to support a few people remotely, and it works very well.  And yes, Remote Desktop Manager supports Remote Assistance connections.

Answer (score 2):

If every computer is Windows - I wouldn't even bother with VNC.  Just use the Remote Desktop Connection provided via Windows.  (Note:  Only included with Pro, Ultimate, and Business versions.)  Couple resources to get you started:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Remote-Desktop-Connection-frequently-asked-questions

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/turn-on-remote-desktop-in-windows-vista/

Comment: Remote desktop doesn't allow you to physically control their system via their account though right? Meaning I create my own login instance when I use remote login, instead of just connecting to their already logged in machine. That creates problems when someone is installing something (they need help with what they see on their screen).

Answer (score 0):

Some vendors have free editions, [like this one.](http://www.realvnc.com/products/download.html)  Do a Google search and you should find plenty of resources.  Also, I'm sure SU has several posts on the topic as well.

Comment: I found plenty of VNC tools, many of them I've used in the past. As mentioned in the OP, I need a way to manage them centrally. 

Telling me to google it certainly isn't helpful....

Comment: PS - I used to use RealVNC and it worked well for my purposes...

Comment: Have you read the docs for these VNC searches you have done?  Sometimes the main features are buried in the documentation and easily overlooked.

Comment: I don't mean this to be attacking in any way, but isn't that what SU is for? So I can ask questions when they aren't readily available?

Comment: Yes, but also many users ask questions before doing the proper research (I know I have...).  No offense taken, I was just suggesting.  Basically I answered your question with a free VNC, and the Centralized Manager aspect may be tough to find...  No problems here...  Good luck finding what you need.

Answer (score -1):

An open source, tabbed, multi-protocol, remote connections manager: 
https://mremoteng.org/